# bndtools debug bundle in equinox GUI

Tags: bndtools

I am converting a PDE plugin into a bnd bradle build. I have a runbnd file, see below, which resolves nicely to include all custom and external dependencies. If I click on either "Run OSGi" or "Debug OSGi" the bundle is somehow started as I can see from the Console. But no equinox or eclipse services are started, so I have no way to interact with my plugin. I don't want a felix shell - this is not sufficient - I need a full eclipse GUI started up... how can I do this? What capability is missing?

There is quite some tutorials around bndtools etc out there. But in 99% of cases they stop at felix. So I am stuck right now.

```
-runfw: org.eclipse.osgi;version='[3.18.200.v20221116-1324,3.18.200.v20221116-1324]'
-runee: JavaSE-17

-runrequires: \
    bnd.identity;id=virtual-environment,\
    bnd.identity;id='org.eclipse.osgi'

-runsystempackages: 

-runbundles: \
    async-api;version='[2.0.5,2.0.6)',\
    basic-codecs;version='[2.0.4,2.0.5)',\
    collection-api;version='[2.0.5,2.0.6)',\
    com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-annotations;version='[2.13.3,2.13.4)',\
    com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-core;version='[2.13.3,2.13.4)',\
    com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-databind;version='[2.13.2,2.13.3)',\
    com.ibm.icu;version='[72.1.0,72.1.1)',\
    common-api;version='[2.0.9,2.0.10)',\
    crypto-api;version='[2.0.5,2.0.6)',\
    generic-model-json-codec;version='[2.0.6,2.0.7)',\
    gm-core-api;version='[2.0.45,2.0.46)',\
    ioc-annotations;version='[2.0.5,2.0.6)',\
    jakarta.servlet-api;version='[4.0.0,4.0.1)',\
    jsinterop-base;version='[2.0.7,2.0.8)',\
    logging;version='[2.0.11,2.0.12)',\
    logging-ndc;version='[2.0.5,2.0.6)',\
    marshaller-api;version='[2.0.8,2.0.9)',\
    org.apache.commons.commons-fileupload;version='[1.4.0,1.4.1)',\
    org.apache.commons.commons-io;version='[2.11.0,2.11.1)',\
    org.apache.commons.lang;version='[2.6.0,2.6.1)',\
    org.eclipse.core.commands;version='[3.10.300,3.10.301)',\
    org.eclipse.core.contenttype;version='[3.8.200,3.8.201)',\
    org.eclipse.core.databinding;version='[1.11.200,1.11.201)',\
    org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable;version='[1.12.100,1.12.101)',\
    org.eclipse.core.databinding.property;version='[1.9.100,1.9.101)',\
    org.eclipse.core.expressions;version='[3.8.200,3.8.201)',\
    org.eclipse.core.filebuffers;version='[3.7.200,3.7.201)',\
    org.eclipse.core.filesystem;version='[1.9.500,1.9.501)',\
    org.eclipse.core.jobs;version='[3.13.200,3.13.201)',\
    org.eclipse.core.resources;version='[3.18.100,3.18.101)',\
    org.eclipse.core.runtime;version='[3.26.100,3.26.101)',\
    org.eclipse.core.variables;version='[3.5.100,3.5.101)',\
    org.eclipse.debug.core;version='[3.20.0,3.20.1)',\
    org.eclipse.equinox.app;version='[1.6.200,1.6.201)',\
    org.eclipse.equinox.common;version='[3.17.0,3.17.1)',\
    org.eclipse.equinox.http.registry;version='[1.3.200,1.3.201)',\
    org.eclipse.equinox.preferences;version='[3.10.100,3.10.101)',\
    org.eclipse.equinox.registry;version='[3.11.200,3.11.201)',\
    org.eclipse.help;version='[3.9.100,3.9.101)',\
    org.eclipse.jdt.core;version='[3.32.0,3.32.1)',\
    org.eclipse.jdt.core.manipulation;version='[1.17.0,1.17.1)',\
    org.eclipse.jdt.debug;version='[3.20.0,3.20.1)',\
    org.eclipse.jdt.launching;version='[3.19.800,3.19.801)',\
    org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring;version='[3.13.0,3.13.1)',\
    org.eclipse.osgi.services;version='[3.11.100,3.11.101)',\
    org.eclipse.rap.fileupload;version='[3.23.0,3.23.1)',\
    org.eclipse.rap.jface;version='[3.23.0,3.23.1)',\
    org.eclipse.rap.jface.databinding;version='[3.23.0,3.23.1)',\
    org.eclipse.rap.rwt;version='[3.23.0,3.23.1)',\
    org.eclipse.rap.rwt.osgi;version='[3.23.0,3.23.1)',\
    org.eclipse.rap.ui.workbench;version='[3.23.0,3.23.1)',\
    org.eclipse.swt;version='[3.122.0,3.122.1)',\
    org.eclipse.text;version='[3.12.300,3.12.301)',\
    org.osgi.service.cm;version='[1.6.1,1.6.2)',\
    org.osgi.service.component;version='[1.5.0,1.5.1)',\
    org.osgi.service.device;version='[1.1.1,1.1.2)',\
    org.osgi.service.event;version='[1.4.1,1.4.2)',\
    org.osgi.service.metatype;version='[1.4.1,1.4.2)',\
    org.osgi.service.prefs;version='[1.1.2,1.1.3)',\
    org.osgi.service.provisioning;version='[1.2.0,1.2.1)',\
    org.osgi.service.upnp;version='[1.2.1,1.2.2)',\
    org.osgi.service.useradmin;version='[1.1.1,1.1.2)',\
    org.osgi.service.wireadmin;version='[1.0.2,1.0.3)',\
    org.osgi.util.function;version='[1.2.0,1.2.1)',\
    org.osgi.util.promise;version='[1.2.0,1.2.1)',\
    platform-api;version='[2.0.20,2.0.21)',\
    platform-exceptions;version='[2.0.5,2.0.6)',\
    virtual-environment;version=snapshot,\
    virtual-environment-plugin-configuration-model;version='[1.0.4,1.0.5)',\
    xml-utils;version='[2.0.5,2.0.6)',\
    org.eclipse.swt.gtk.linux.ppc64le;version='[3.122.0,3.122.1)'
```

I also attach the generated MANIFEST in case this may be useful

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bnd-LastModified: 1687764864673
Bundle-ActivationPolicy: lazy
Bundle-Activator: com.braintribe.devrock.virtualenvironment.VirtualEnv
 ironmentPlugin
Bundle-Localization: plugin
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: virtual-environment
Bundle-SymbolicName: virtual-environment
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0.202306260734
Created-By: 17.0.5 (Eclipse Adoptium)
Export-Package: com.braintribe.devrock.virtualenvironment.listener;ver
 sion="1.0.0",com.braintribe.devrock.virtualenvironment.plugin.prefere
 nces;version="1.0.0";uses:="com.braintribe.codec,com.braintribe.model
 .malaclypse.cfg.preferences.ve,org.eclipse.jface.preference",com.brai
 ntribe.devrock.virtualenvironment.plugin.preferences.page.environment
 ;version="1.0.0";uses:="com.braintribe.devrock.virtualenvironment.lis
 tener,com.braintribe.model.malaclypse.cfg.preferences.ve,org.eclipse.
 jface.preference,org.eclipse.jface.viewers,org.eclipse.swt.graphics,o
 rg.eclipse.swt.widgets,org.eclipse.ui",com.braintribe.devrock.virtual
 environment.variable;version="1.0.0";uses:="org.eclipse.ui",com.brain
 tribe.devrock.virtualenvironment.variable.resolver;version="1.0.0";us
 es:="org.eclipse.jface.text.templates"
Import-Package: com.braintribe.cc.lcd;version="[2.0,3)",com.braintribe
 .codec;version="[2.0,3)",com.braintribe.codec.json.genericmodel;versi
 on="[2.0,3)",com.braintribe.devrock.virtualenvironment.listener;versi
 on="[1.0,2)",com.braintribe.devrock.virtualenvironment.plugin.prefere
 nces;version="[1.0,2)",com.braintribe.devrock.virtualenvironment.vari
 able.resolver;version="[1.0,2)",com.braintribe.model.generic;version=
 "[2.0,3)",com.braintribe.model.generic.reflection;version="[2.0,3)",c
 om.braintribe.model.malaclypse.cfg.preferences.ve;version="[1.0,2)",c
 om.braintribe.utils;version="[2.0,3)",java.io,java.lang,java.util,org
 .eclipse.core.resources,org.eclipse.core.runtime;version="[3.5,4)";co
 mmon=split,org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui,org.eclipse.jface.dialogs,org.
 eclipse.jface.layout,org.eclipse.jface.preference,org.eclipse.jface.r
 esource,org.eclipse.jface.text.templates;text=split,org.eclipse.jface
 .viewers,org.eclipse.swt.custom,org.eclipse.swt.events,org.eclipse.sw
 t.graphics,org.eclipse.swt.layout,org.eclipse.swt.widgets,org.eclipse
 .ui;ui.workbench=split,org.eclipse.ui.plugin,org.osgi.framework;versi
 on="[1.10,2)"
Private-Package: com.braintribe.devrock.virtualenvironment;version="1.
 0.0",com.braintribe.devrock.commons.tableviewer;version="1.0.0",com.b
 raintribe.devrock.preferences.contributer;version="1.0.0",com.braintr
 ibe.devrock.preferences.control;version="1.0.0",com.braintribe.devroc
 k.preferences.contributer.implementation;version="1.0.0",com.braintri
 be.devrock.preferences.commons;version="1.0.0"
Require-Capability: osgi.ee;filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=17))"
Tool: Bnd-6.4.0.202211291949
```

Comment: You can habe a llok at my minimalistic but complete eclipse rcp app example. https://github.com/klibio/example.bnd.rcp Feel free to get in touch for questions.

Comment: Thank you very much. I was looking for information like this for weeks. There is a lot, but never quite what I needed. I am very grateful and will carefully look your project.... I will come back with questions....